# Image Overlay Using Z-Index But Cannot See Elements Beneath

Tags: css, image, overlay, positioning

I'm trying to accomplish the following where I have some text on the left side of the page and an graphic on the right hand side. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5jAy.png

I'm using Bootstrap  4 and everything has been going well so far. However, when trying to incorporate the graphic into the site, I am running into two problems:

1. I always want the graphic to be positioned the same way no matter what screen size the website is being displayed on. Currently I am setting the graphic's width to 75%. When I preview on a smaller screen, the graphic is not even visible because the width is so small in regards to the width of the viewport. I am using absolute positioning, but this seems to change depending on the screen size.
2. When previewed on a larger monitor, the graphic displays on-top of my text. Now, I didn't think this would be a problem. I've saved my graphic as a png to allow for transparency and I've given my graphic a higher z-index than my text elements. However, the graphic seems to be like a block and covering my text elements, as seen here. 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk5QX.png

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix either issue?

HTML:

```
<section class="header">
<div class="container-fluid p-4">
    <img class="logo" width="52" height="57" src="img/BraydonCoyerLogoIcon.png" alt="Personal Logo">
    <img src="img/decoration1.png" alt="Colorful Decorations" class="decoration">
</div>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="greeting">
        <div>
            <h1>Hi,</h1>
            <h1>Some <span class="highlight">Text</span></h1>
            <hr align="left"/>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    background-color: #262628;
    color: #eaeaea;
    font-family: "Varela Round", Helvetica, Arial;
}

.greeting {
    margin-top: 10em;
}

.greeting h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
}

.highlight {
    color: #f99e46;
}

.slogan {
    font-size: 20px;
}
hr {
    background-color: white;
    width: 50%;
}

.decoration {
    width: 75%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: initial;
    top: -150px;
    left: 520px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to use percentage for left position: `left: 50%`
2. Looks like your decoration image inherits `background-color: #262628;` from wildcard selector

Comment: Thanks for the reply - using your suggestions, I think I've come up with something I like. However, now my website has a horizontal scrollbar because half of the decoration is on the far right side of the screen. Is there a way to remove the horizontal scrollbar (I've had lots of trouble with this before when previewing on mobile screens)?

Comment: body { overflow-x: hidden; }